# Знаки препинания при прилагательных

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прилагательные, однородные-неоднородные-определения

"И он, подобно маленькому(,) резвому ребенку, побежал вниз по тропинке".

Где скобочки может быть запятая? Я рассматриваю случай, что это характеристика предмета с разных сторон.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что сложность в выборе пунктуации возникла потому, что оба прилагательных являются качественными. Но описывают-то они ребенка с разных позиций: *маленький* — размер (рост) или возраст, *резвый* — подвижность.
Главной характеристикой, мне кажется, здесь является все-таки прилагательное "резвый" (ведь кто-то побежал; резвые неизменно быстроноги и проворны, а вот просто маленькие — не всегда).
Я бы не стала ставить запятую, посчитав определения неоднородными (если только в предыдущем тексте не обозначены какие-либо особые параметры —  в этом *Серж* прав (см. комментарий)).
**И он, подобно маленькому резвому ребенку, побежал вниз по тропинке.**

*В этот момент **маленький резвый** жеребенок — головная боль торговца — подбежал к гончару и ткнулся носом в его руку* (С. Гхош. Легенды и предания Древней Индии).

*Это тот самый **маленький резвый** мальчишка, который нас всех бесит на корабле, хитрый, как обезьяна, веселый, как зяблик...* (О. Фере. Четыре фрейлины двора Людовика XIV).

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85,%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F.)

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, ребёнок характеризуется с разных сторон, *запятая не нужна.*

Comment: А меня сомнение одолевает. При характеристике _реальных_ детей (_Маленькие, резвые дети побежали вниз по тропинке_ - здесь просто перечисляют наблюдаемые признаки) так и было бы. Но здесь строят _абстрактный_ образ ребёнка, с которым производят сравнение. Мол, представьте себе **маленького** ребенка (_класс субъектов_). Он бегает по тропинке - не потому, что маленький, а потому, что **резвый** (_характеристика субъекта_: резвый из числа детей малого возраста). Это создает ощущение _неоднородности_ признаков (при которой запятая не ставится) и даже желание переставить местами прилагательные.

Comment: @Alex_ander: ну не знаю. Запятую в любом случае мне почему-то не хочется ставить. А в примере в скобках вы случайно запятую поставили? Пишете же, что так бы и было, то есть, как я понял, как я предложил.

Comment: Я не совсем внимательно прочитал ответ (не дочитал до вывода) - воспринял его как согласие с автором вопроса о _возможности_ поставить запятую. В своём примере я её допускаю - как оценку со стороны (он маленькие и резвые); в исходном - нет.

Comment: @Alex-ander, на мой взгляд запятая вариативна. Причем в правилах оговариваются такие случаи. Думаю, нужен более широкий контекст. Автору виднее.